# How fix bug show/hide submenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a navigation menu: https://jsfiddle.net/f73wa3w1/1/

I have one bug. If we click on `li.submenu_f` then `li.submenu_s` and again on `li.submenu` we find bug. Screenshot: http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/2016/06/07/0017/1846/1148726/26/0c40123255.jpg

I don't know how to fix this. Can any one help me?

```js
$('.cc_name').click(function() {
  $('.categories').stop().slideToggle(300);
})

$('.submenu_f > a').click(function() {
  $('.submenu_f ul').slideUp(300);
  $(this).parent().children('ul').stop().slideToggle(300);
})

$('.submenu_s > a').click(function() {
  $('.submenu_s ul').slideUp(300);
  $(this).parent().children('ul').stop().slideToggle(300);
})
```

```css
.categories,
#categories ul li ul,
#categories ul li ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="categories">
    <div class="cc_name">Каталог товаров</div>
    <div class="categories">
        <ul>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Электроника</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Бытовая техника</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Компьютеры</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Товары для дома</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Товары для авто</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Сад и огород</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Строительство и ремонт</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon submenu_f">
                <a href="#" title="">Подарки и украшения</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Теле-видео-аудио техника</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Телефоны и связь</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu_s">
                        <a href="#" title="">Фото и видео</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Плиты</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Вытяжки</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Холодильники</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Духовые шкафы</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Варочные поверхности</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Посудомоечные машины</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Стиральные машины</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Аксессуары</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Портативная электроника</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Прочая электроника</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#" title="">Элементы питания</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Парфюмерия и косметика</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Товары для детей</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Товары для спорта и отдыха</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Товары для животных</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Одежда и обувь</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon"><a href="#" title="">Бытовая химия</a></li>
            <li class="cat_icon submenu_f"><a href="#" title="">Фермерские товары</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submenu_s">
                        <a href="">1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><a href="">1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu_s">
                        <a href="">2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class=""><a href="">2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that JQuery UI requires specific styles for the height of the element being toggled. You can find a work around by making the height of the elements `auto` at specific points in the animation. When opening the lists, remove the auto height. However, when closing the lists, add the auto height:

```
$('.cc_name').click(function(){
        $('.categories').stop().slideToggle(300);
})

$('.submenu_f > a').click(function(){
  $('.submenu_f ul').removeClass('modify-height');
    $(this).parent().children('ul').stop().slideToggle(300,function(){
    $(this).addClass('modify-height');
  });
})

$('.submenu_s > a').click(function(){
  $('.submenu_s ul').removeClass('modify-height');
    $(this).parent().children('ul').stop().slideToggle(300,function(){
    $(this).addClass('modify-height');
  });
})
```

For the toggling statement, I added a callback to add/remove a class that modifies the height property. Here is the added CSS:

```
.modify-height{
  height: auto !important;
}
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f73wa3w1/5/

**Note:** I have removed the other slide toggle statements. This will work even with them there, but you will notice a little choppiness when trying to recreate the problem.

**UPDATED A MORE ELEGANT SOLUTION**

The issue is that you are not closing the bottom-most submenu properly. There are no callbacks in this code and it is a minor tweak from your original:

```
$('.cc_name').click(function(){
        $('.categories').stop().slideToggle(300);
})

$('.submenu_f > a').click(function(){
  $('.submenu_s ul').slideUp(300); //slide up the child 'ul' here
  $(this).delay(300).parent().children('ul').stop().slideToggle(300); //add a delay equal to the child 'ul' animation to compensate for any lag
})

$('.submenu_s > a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('ul').stop().slideToggle(300);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f73wa3w1/6/

Comment: Apologies, for some reason the 3rd clicking list in your initial fiddle wasn't working. I thought that was the problem. I updated the solution.

Comment: Thank you, but when we click on li.submenu_f and then we click on second li.submenu_f - first not closed, need when we click on li.submenu_f only him see

Comment: I have updated the response. Follow that pattern for every level of sublists.

Answer (score 0):

It's working on my PC? Maybe it's a browser thing

[image]

Comment: Here's a bug in my gif screenshot